# function memcpy() is closing the program

Tags: c, opencv, memcpy

When compiler encounters the function memcpy(), program stops working and shows messagebox "`name_program has stopped working`".

This is the function:

```
IplImage* hBitmap2Ipl(HBITMAP hBmp)
{
    BITMAP bmp;
    ::GetObject(hBmp,sizeof(BITMAP),&bmp);
    int nChannels = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? 1 : bmp.bmBitsPixel/8 ;

    // get depth color bitmap or grayscale
    int depth = bmp.bmBitsPixel == 1 ? IPL_DEPTH_1U : IPL_DEPTH_8U;

    IplImage* img = cvCreateImageHeader( cvSize(bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight), depth,
        nChannels );

    // Copy bitmap data to IplImage
    img->imageData = (char*)malloc(bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*nChannels*sizeof(char));

    memcpy(img->imageData,(char*)(bmp.bmBits),bmp.bmHeight*bmp.bmWidth*nChannels);

    return img;
}
```

But this works perfectly:

```
int a[10];
int b[10];
memcpy(a, b, 10);
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: add "assert(img->imageData);" after malloc to detect size issue

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: You mean verify `malloc` succeeded? Aside from testing the wrong condition, that should not be a debug-assertion.

Comment: `(char*)(bmp.bmBits)` Is that an address?

Comment: Before using `memcpy`, verify that `bmp.bmHeight * bmp.bmWidth*nChannels` is not larger than the size of `img->imageData`.

Comment: I think the problem is most likely with `bmp.bmBits`. A quick glance at MSDN indicates that there are case where `GetObject` doesn't set that value. You need to figure out if you are in one of those cases and then determine how go from there to get the data you want.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Did you noticed that the arguments to `malloc` and `memcpy`-length are identical? How could the length argument larger then the size of `img->ImageData`?

Comment: What happens if you run it in a debugger ?

Answer (score 1):

`GetObject` won't return a valid pointer for the `bmBits` member - it only populates the other members of the structure.

You need to use something like [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Comment: I try use GetDIBits, but it doesn't work correct. It is returning 0.